# Which are functions of bounded variations?

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Let $f, g : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as follows:
$f(x) = x^2 \sin (1/x)$ if $x = 0$, $f(0)=0$

$g(x) = \sqrt{x} \sin (1/x)$ if $x = 0, g(0) = 0$.

Which are functions of bounded variations?Every polynomial in a compact interval is of BV?

Could any one just tell me what is the main result to see whether a function is of BV? Derivative bounded?

Comment: related problems:[(I)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187760/variation-of-fx-x-eta-sin-varepsilon-frac1x), [(II)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332373/math-analysis-problem-dealing-with-bounded-variation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, bounded derivative implies BV. I explained this in your older question [which condition says that $f$ is necessarily bounded variation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/364459/79365). Since $f$ has bounded derivative, it is in BV.

A function with unbounded derivative could also be in BV, for example $\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$ is BV because it's monotone. More generally, a function with finitely many  maxima and minima on an interval is BV.

But $g$ has unbounded derivative *and* infinite number of maxima and minima on an interval. In such a situation you should look at the peaks and troughs of its graph and try to estimate the sum of differences $\sum |\Delta f_i|$ between them. It is not necessary to precisely locate the maxima and minima. The fact that 
$$g((\pi/2+2\pi n)^{-1})=(\pi/2+2\pi n)^{-1/2},\quad g((3\pi/2+2\pi n)^{-1})=-(3\pi/2+2\pi n)^{-1/2}$$
gives you enough information about $g$ to conclude it is not BV.